# How can I store custom object in WPF DataGrid cell?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How can I store custom object in WPF DataGrid cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`DataGridTemplateColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Custom Column">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- whatever you like in here -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridtemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's all of I need :). Can you help me with another problem?
How can I set dependence between font color and integer value? For example, for value "4" color is green, for value "-3" - red. *don't know*

Comment: @Dmitriy: no problem. If you have another question, feel free to create a new topic for it rather than attempting to address it here.