# WPF Newbie - How do I store the entire Binding object in a Row of the DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF, so there may be an easy answer to this, but it isn't obvious to me.

The grid obviously represents a collection of my Configured Port objects. I want to store the Configured Port object (which is the Binding for each row) in order to pass it to the next UserControl in the MVVM chain when a grid cell is clicked.

I did find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583594/how-can-i-store-custom-object-in-wpf-datagrid-cell), but the commented section is exactly what I am missing.

Thanks in advance, I'm sure there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this (everything except for the inner most xaml was taken from the other SO post you linked to:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
   <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Custom Column">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Tag="{Binding}" Content="Click Me" Click="Button_ClickHandler"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridtemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Then the source for the click handler:

```
private void Button_ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var clickedConfiguredPort = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag as ConfiguredPort;
    DoStuff(clickedConfiguredPort);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1b694f75-7621-4c88-8055-6c31c601c87f/

When I did it, I had predefined columns so I used the second solution, but if you are wanting to auto generate the columns, you could implement the first solution.